# Easier/terser mechanism for translating CMake option into preprocessor definitions?

Tags: cmake, definition, cmake-cache

I find myself repeating the following segment of code in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
option(SOME_OPT "Some option" ON)
if (SOME_OPT)
    target_compile_definitions(my_app SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT)
endif()
```

(and occasionally something similar but with a string value for the `-D`).

Is there a mechanism in CMake (never mind the version) which makes this easier, or more terse?

Comment: You could always define a macro: `macro(my_add_option OPTION DOC DEFAULT) option(${OPTION} ${DOC} ${DEFAULT}) if (${OPTION}) add_definitions(${ARGN}) endif() endmacro()` `my_add_option(SOME_OPT "Some option" ON -DSOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT) my_add_option(FOO_OPT "foo option" ON FOO=1 BAR=0)`

Comment: @fabian - better to do it as a function to avoid variable scoping issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Using generator expressions

Here's one option using target properties and generator expressions:

```
option(SOME_OPT1 "Some option 1" ON)
option(SOME_OPT2 "Some option 2" OFF)
option(SOME_OPT3 "Some option 3" ON)

target_compile_definitions(my_app PRIVATE
  $<$<BOOL:${SOME_OPT1}>:SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT1>
  $<$<BOOL:${SOME_OPT2}>:SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT2>
  $<$<BOOL:${SOME_OPT3}>:SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT3>
)
```

The `$<BOOL:${var}>` dance is necessary to translate truthy/falsey CMake values to either `1` or `0`, as the generator expression mini-language expects.

### Option 2: A generated "configure file"

Another option if you have many of these is to use the `configure_file` command to create a header with the relevant information. Create a header called `config.h.in` (as an example) with the following contents:

```
#ifndef MYPROJ_CONFIG_H
#define MYPROJ_CONFIG_H

#cmakedefine SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT1
#cmakedefine SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT2
#cmakedefine01 SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT3

#endif
```

The `#cmakedefine VAR` directive is processed by `configure_file` to set `VAR` if `VAR` is defined in the CMakeLists.txt as something truthy and to comment out the line if not. The `01` variant always defines `VAR`, but sets it to either `0` or `1`.

Then in your CMakeLists.txt you could write:

```
option(SOME_OPT1 "Some option 1" ON)
option(SOME_OPT2 "Some option 2" OFF)
option(SOME_OPT3 "Some option 3" ON)

# Setting these variables exposes them to configure_file below
set(SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT1 "${SOME_OPT1}")
set(SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT2 "${SOME_OPT2}")
set(SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT3 "${SOME_OPT3}")

configure_file(config.h.in config.h)

target_include_directories(my_app PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>")
```

Your source files could then `#include <config.h>`, which would be, by default:

```
#ifndef MYPROJ_CONFIG_H
#define MYPROJ_CONFIG_H

#define SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT1
/* #undef SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT2 */
#define SOME_IDENTIFIER_HERE_RELATED_TO_OPT3 1

#endif
```

---

Both options cost one line of overhead per option, though the first approach is a little noisy and the second approach costs a file. However, the second approach *also* lets you add additional preprocessor code that might be better placed together in the configured file. It can also substitute CMake variable *values* via the `@VAR@` syntax. See the documentation for more detail: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html

Comment: Alex - I amended the question to have  target-specific compile definitions, since I don't want to "muddy the waters" with this issue. Sorry about that; I'm only asking about avoiding the repeated typing.

Comment: @einpoklum - I have edited my answer down to the two approaches I would recommend in light of that.